# NHibernate impersonation with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, impersonation

The WCF service is running under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account, the request is impersonated with other account (which is admin on the DB), but NHibernate is throwing an exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Any ideas?

Comment: are you able to connect to the db server from your app server using management studio with that user?

Comment: have you debugged the app server to verify that indeed the process is run with impersonation of that user?

Comment: @sJhonny: Yes :) It looks like NHibernate is doing something unusual.

Comment: well, I'm out of ideas... :) sorry i couldn't be of more help. the only things I can offer is posting on nHusers google group, and if all else fails- either run your service under a different user and drop the impersonation or dive into nH source to try and find out what the problem is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate had nothing to do with the problem. It was imopersonation setup problem. [The solution could be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/MultiHopImpersonation.aspx).